# Is there mathematical verification for TBPTT (truncated back propagation through time)

Tags: rnn, gradient-descent, mathematics

My question is in the title. I'm currently looking for a paper or academic reference to that algorithm, even in a novel framework.

Thank you for all possible replies,

Answer (score 0):

Truncated Backpropagation Through Time (truncated BPTT) is a widespread method for learning recurrent computational graphs. Truncated BPTT keeps the computational benefits of Backpropagation Through Time (BPTT) while relieving the need for a complete backtrack through the whole data sequence at every step. More on [Unbiasing Truncated Backpropagation Through Time](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08209)

From the paper [On the difficulty of training Recurrent Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.5063.pdf)

From stats.exchange answer by [itzjustricky](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/283275/260797)

> The truncated part of Truncated Backpropagation through Time simply refers to at which point in time to stop calculating the gradients for the backpropagation phase.
>
> Let's say you truncate after $k$ steps then the difference is you calculate the below instead.
>
> $$
> \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial A}\approx\sum_{t=T-k}^{T}\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial h_{t}}\frac{\partial^{+}{h_{t}}}{\partial A}=\sum_{t=T-k}^{T}(\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial h_{t}}\odot f'(Ah_{t-1}+Bx_{t}))h_{t-1}^{T}.
> $$
>
> Where $\frac{\partial^{+}}{\partial{A}}$ is the "immediate" partial wrt A, i.e. the one that assumes all terms other than an explicit A are constant.